# R data.table setkey on numeric column

Tags: r, data.table

Do we really need to add `J()` to select numeric column?

We can get the result of character column without `J()`.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
setkey(DT,x)  
DT["a"]  
#    x y v
# 1: a 1 1
# 2: a 3 2
# 3: a 6 3

setkey(DT,y)  
DT["1"]  
# Error in `[.data.table`(DT, "1") : 
#  typeof x.y (double) != typeof i.y (character)

# Is it a bug?

DT[J(1)]
#    y x v
# 1: 1 a 1
# 2: 1 b 4
# 3: 1 c 7
```

Thanks!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck - Why not post this as an answer?

Comment: OK. Have transferred it to answers.

Comment: FYI you can also use `.(1)` instead of `J(1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that `DT[1]` is not the same as `DT[J(1)]` is that there are TWO different interpretations that we might want:

1. the first row, `DT[1]`
2. all rows for which the key equals `1`, `DT[J(1)]`

The potential ambiguity only exists if the first argument is numeric which is why there are two different notations for the two situations.

In the case of a character key this potential ambiguity does not arise since a character argument could only mean the second case.

Also, `DT["1"]` is an error in the code of the question since the key in the example is not character and data.table does not perform coercion of types here.